Vue-chartjs TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'datasets' in undefined
I got this error trying to use vue-chartjs LineChart in Vue 3.
<template>
  <va-modal blur size="large" v-model="showCountryModal" no-padding>
    <template #content="{ ok }">

      <span v-if="!pending">
        <va-card-title>
          <h2>{{ this.countryDetails.country }}</h2>
        </va-card-title>
        <va-card-content>
          
          <Line :data="data" :options="options" />   

        </va-card-content>
        <va-card-actions>
          <va-button @click="ok" color="warning">Ok!</va-button>
        </va-card-actions>
      </span>
      <div v-else class="d-flex justify--center" style="width: 100%">
        <hollow-dots-spinner animation-duration="1000" color="#8bb604" size="80" />
      </div>
    </template> 

  </va-modal>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState } from "pinia";
import { HollowDotsSpinner } from "epic-spinners";
import {
  Chart as ChartJS,
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
  PointElement,
  LineElement,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  Legend
} from 'chart.js'

import { Line } from 'vue-chartjs'

ChartJS.register(
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
  PointElement,
  LineElement,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  Legend
  )

export default {
  name: "Graph",
  components: { HollowDotsSpinner, Line },
  props: { 
    pending: false,
    showCountryModal: false, 
    countryDetails: {
      type: Object,
    },
    countryCodeStats: {
      type: Object,
    },
    selected_country: {
      type: Object,
    },
    edits: false,
    allGroupNames: {
      type: Object,
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      data: {
        labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
        datasets: [
          {
            label: 'Data One',
            backgroundColor: '#f87979',
            data: [40, 39, 10, 40, 39, 80, 40]
          }
        ]
      }, 
      options: {
        responsive: true
      }
    }
  }, 
  
}
</script>
 

I am getting this error:
vue-chartjs.js?v=757747f2:219 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'datasets' in undefined
at vue-chartjs.js?v=757747f2:219:24
at callWithErrorHandling (chunk-WDIZNU4V.js?v=757747f2:1543:18)
at callWithAsyncErrorHandling (chunk-WDIZNU4V.js?v=757747f2:1551:17)
at hook.__weh.hook.__weh (chunk-WDIZNU4V.js?v=757747f2:3130:19)
at flushPostFlushCbs (chunk-WDIZNU4V.js?v=757747f2:1699:41)
at flushJobs (chunk-WDIZNU4V.js?v=757747f2:1727:5)
Here is also the version of vue and chartjs package:
"vue": "^3.2.25",
"vue-chartjs": "^4.1.2",


There's nothing in the provided data you'd expect to cause an error, in fact it looks very similar to data you'd find in the documentation.  As it is, there's not enough information to reproduce the issue, and therefore not enough information to provide an answer.  You'll need to provide more information about your app.  See how to create an MCVE.

stackblitz showing working line chart with your data.

I have posted the full code. I have no idea why I am getting this error. Please kindly assist

I was able to resolved this issue.
According to the documentation vue-chartjs for version 4.1.2 here:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-chartjs/v/4.1.2
The necessary props to pass to the chart components are
:chart-options="chartOptions"
:chart-data="chartData"
:chart-id="chartId"
:dataset-id-key="datasetIdKey"
:plugins="plugins"
:css-classes="cssClasses"
:styles="styles"
:width="width"
:height="height"

e.g.

However, this props has been changed in future version of this package. I would advice to check the version of the package you installed and check the readme of this package version here https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-chartjs
